# Angular JS input ng-model search bug

Tags: javascript, html, list, angularjs, search

I am experimenting with MEAN ([mean.io](http://mean.io)). I am using the search model like so (basically like [this](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter)):

```
<section data-ng-controller="JobsController" data-ng-init="find()">
    Search: <input ng-model="search.$"><br>
    Search Tag: <input ng-model="search.tag">
    <ul class="jobs unstyled">
        <li id="searchObjResults" data-ng-repeat="jobObj in jobs | filter:search">
            <span>{{jobObj.created | date:'medium'}}</span> /
            <span>{{jobObj.user.name}}</span>
            <h2><a data-ng-href="#!/jobs/{{job._id}}">{{jobObj.title}}</a></h2>
            <div>{{jobObj.content}}</div>
            <div>{{jobObj.reward}}</div>
            <div>{{jobObj.tag}}</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

The `JobsController` is being used, specifically - the `find` function, defined in the `JobsController`, is being called upon load. Here is that function:

```
$scope.find = function() {
    Jobs.query(function(jobs) {
        $scope.jobs = jobs;
    });
};
```

When I search for something using the first input, next to "Search:" - if I type in something, it filters, and when I erase everything from the input, the whole unfiltered database shows up again.

However, when I use the input next to "Search Tag:" - it doesn't repopulate the list to its unfiltered state once I erase everything from the input field. I have to refresh the page to get the unfiltered list back.

The example [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter) has a demo at the bottom, which is very close to mine, but in the demo - it repopulates the list after you erase the input from "Name only" or "Phone only" - which is how I want it to work with `search.tag`.

Comment: What version of angular do you use ? Consider this example http://jsbin.com/oSURIKiD/1/edit?html,js,output I made based on your code. It seems to work fine with angular 1.2.10

Comment: @igor-malyk interesting - i'm using 1.2.10 as well. I have done a lot of tinkering with the files, so I'm wondering if I modified some code somewhere that I need to change back, or to something else. I've gone through pretty much all of the code looking for something I changed...but I haven't noticed anything.

Comment: You mean you tweaked the angular lib ?

Comment: @igor-malyk no - i didn't tweak the lib just controllers and models and some html - could it have anything to do with you declaring "scope.jobs" as an array with all the info - where I am just referencing "jobs" and storing it in "scope.jobs" whenever "data-ng-init" happens.

Comment: "where I am just referencing "jobs""
Does Jobs.query return jobs as array of objects ?

Comment: Try removing the "data-ng-init"
and adding to the controller:

$scope.jobs = [];
$scope.jobs = $scope.find();

Comment: @igor-malyk I believe so - here (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource) it says "/ We can retrieve a collection from the server
var cards = CreditCard.query(function() {
  // GET: /user/123/card
  // server returns: [ {id:456, number:'1234', name:'Smith'} ];"

Comment: Please see my comment above about the removing data-ng-init. It would be much easier to analyze the issue if you provided the planker/jsfiddle/jsbin with the example which doesn't work.

Comment: I tried removing "data-ng-init" and adding what you typed to just under "$scope.global = Global" - the only variable declaration in the "JobsController" - and now when I reload it, the jobs aren't being displayed at all. I'll make a fiddle.

Comment: @igor-malyk can't get it to do what I want to - but this is it basically - http://jsfiddle.net/neQsL/

Comment: Example won't work like that, because the services you are injecting `Global, Jobs` aren't defined. Anyway, I've made a mistake, of course, please try 
`$scope.jobs = [];
 $scope.find();`

Comment: @IgorMalyk I know why the fiddle isn't working - I just figured you'd get it anyway...made the changes - still not showing the list of jobs.

Comment: Are there any exceptions in the console ? I distilled your fiddle to this http://jsbin.com/uSABApi/38/edit?html,js,output and it does work. Perhaps there are some errors related to the jobs retrieval ?

Comment: @igor-malyk yes actually - "Error: $scope.find is not a function" in angular.js (line 7978)

Comment: In your example it happens because scope.find() is called before it is defined. Please move the  

'$scope.findOne = function() {
        Jobs.get({
            jobId: $routeParams.jobId
        }, function(job) {
            $scope.job = job;
        });
    };'

definition to the very top of the function scope.

Comment: @igor-malyk moved $scope.findOne to top - had to move $scope.find to the top as well - now it is displaying the jobs...but I am still having the original filtering problem after using the "Search Tag:" input.

Comment: When you repeat this case and the array is not repopulated are there any exceptions ? Could it be that only the jobs which don't have tags at all == have an empty array or null instead of it don't get restored ?

Comment: @IgorMalyk not sure - when a job is created this is the default tag code in the model Schema: "tag: {
        type: Array,
        default: null,
        trim: true
    },"

Comment: @IgorMalyk ok - one thing that is happening now is that when I erase the input from the search tag field it always repopulates only with the one input that i made have a tag for the test. The rest of the list is gone.

Comment: Yes I noticed it. Sorry don't have a quick answer, have to debug it. It's late at my place already, if you need an answer asap you'd better ask a more specific question at SO. I'll come back tomorrow.

Comment: @IgorMalyk http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488859/angular-js-mean-stack-search-bug